# When exactly is onAppear called in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Can anyone explain exactly when `onAppear` is called in SwiftUI. Docs say `A view that triggers action when this view appears.`

When the view with `onAppear` changes and is thus rendered again is probably clear. But what about:

1. When one of its child views changes?
2. When one of its siblings changes?
3. When its parent changes?
4. When navigating back in a NavigationView?
5. When changing back to a tab view that was previously on the screen, but has not otherwise changed?
6. Any time it appears on the screen?
7. When app returns from background?
8. ...

Comment: The 3rd and 4th really are dependent on the implementation of `NavigationView` or `TabView` (whether or not the view is removed from the hierarchy). For the others: 1 & 2) Not called since the view has already appeared. 3) If the view was already in the view hierarchy, it's not called. If it only just appeared (e.g. if an `if` was used) then onAppear would be triggered. 4 & 5) I wouldn't know without checking, but iirc both do trigger onAppear again.

Comment: In general, if a view is now appearing when it wasn't already in the view hierarchy before, `onAppear` is called. An update in child views won't affect it. If a view changes identity, it won't cause `onAppear` to be called either.

Comment: From what I observed for 4 : if view call navigation link and then back to this view, onAppear is called again : view is not reconstruct but is again displayed on screen. As a complement , your state var are saved.

Comment: The answer is it depends... for all of them. Watch Demystifying SwiftUI. It is all about the View's identity.